# window.open specify content size not window size?

Tags: javascript, no-framework

When you do a `window.open()` you can specify the size of the new window. well depending on a lot of things (like browser, toolbars, etc.) the viewport can vary in size.

For example if I have an image that is 500x400 in size, and I want to open a new window to show exactly that image with no access white space, and no need for scrolling. the window size will vary to make this always true.

So is there a way to specify the viewport size of a new window, instead of the window size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [calculate the viewport size](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/) and tweak your window size accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Only the windowsize but you can calculate the viewport